# PHP file download not working

Tags: php, html, download

I have gone through several of the posted topics on PHP file downloads and I'm not finding any solution.

When I use MAMP and run the .php file it downloads the file perfectly. When I upload it to my server for my web page it downloads the download.php file instead of the pdf I want to allow people to download.

I am not sure what the issue is?

Here is my code: download.php

```
<?php
$file_name = "BrianDaubCV.pdf";
$file_url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.briandaubdesign.com/download.php' . $file_name;
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
readfile($file_url);
?>
```

resume.html

```
<a href="download.php">Download a copy of my resume (PDF)</a>
```

[Here is the website](https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.briandaubdesign.com/pages/resume.html)

Comment: try putting `?` in the URL at the end of php file extension like this:

`$file_url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.briandaubdesign.com/download.php?' . $file_name;`

Comment: your site is treating php files as html. you will need to do something with the web server configs

Comment: Also content-type for pdf is `application/pdf`

Comment: DevZer0 is right. I tried your link and I got the actual PHP code, which shouldn't happen if your webserver is setup to handle PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

Check with this. It is working now. I have added and corrected some lines.

```
$file_name = "BrianDaubCV.pdf";
$file_url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.briandaubdesign.com/download.php' . $file_name;
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name); 
header('Pragma: public');
readfile($file_url);
```